# Failing to execute else statement - code skipping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have stuck in a logical problem  I have a third party package of DayNight. It takes hours input(24-hour-format) to show dayNight effects in scene.

**Now  I have made a clock GUI(360-degree) and as you know it only show 12 digits-format not 24**. I am getting clock needle movement which can be change through mouse drag. Needle z position up to 320 degree which means one degree is equal to 2 minutes and i am taking it as input from GUI. I write below code
         to integrate my clock needle with  my DayNight package in order to integrate GUI with package and passing hour parameter into the package but it not working correctly. Problem is that else condition is skipping.

```
     if (todsky.Cycle.Hour >= 12) {
           Debug.LogError("second");
           var degree = 360 - hourniddle.transform.eulerAngles.z; // as rotation is anti-clock getting rever degree
           var degreeToMintues = degree * 2; //multiply each degree with 2 to get correct minutes
           var MintuestTo24HoursMintueCoverstion = 720 + degreeToMintues; //add 720 mintues into current minute in order to get 24-hour-format
           ConvertMinutesToHours(MintuestTo24HoursMintueCoverstion);
        } else {
           Debug.LogError("Third");
           var degree = 360 - hourniddle.transform.eulerAngles.z;
           var degreeToMintues = degree * 2; //multiply each degree with 2 to get correct minutes
           ConvertMinutesToHours(degreeToMintues);
        }
     void ConvertMinutesToHours(float mintues) {

     result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mintues);
     Debug.Log(result.Hours);
     Debug.Log(result.Hours + ":" + result.TotalHours + ":" + result.Minutes + ":" + result.TotalMinutes);
     todsky.Cycle.Hour = (float) result.TotalHours;
    }
```

Comment: ever heard of [debugging](http://www.justapixel.co.uk/start-using-monodevelops-debugger-with-unity3d/)?

Comment: use but it is logical issue

Comment: put a breakpoint before `if` part. go through code line by line and check values of variables. if nothing works put a `Debug.Break()` inside `else` code

Comment: The only logical answer is that todsky.Cycle.Hour isn't a 24 hour format...